# SFML image not loading

Tags: c++, xcode, image, load, sfml

I am using Xcode with SFML. I placed my file in the Xcode project which copied it to the directory. However, I still am unable to load it into the program. Any ideas?

Code:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    sf::RenderWindow(window);
    window.create(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "My window");

    sf::Texture img;
    if(!img.loadFromFile("colorfull small.jpg")) return 0;

    sf::Sprite sprite;
    sprite.setTexture(img);

    window.draw(sprite);
    window.display();

    while(window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while(window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if(event.type == sf::Event::Closed) window.close();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

compiler:
[image]

directory:
[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple reasons for the error:

From [sfml documentation](http://sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1Image.php#a9e4f2aa8e36d0cabde5ed5a4ef80290b):

> Some format options are not supported, like progressive jpeg.

or

It doesn't find the file because the filename has spaces in it (rename the file, e.g colorfull_small.jpg)

or

The program's working directory does not have the .jpg file (you can print it using `getcwd(NULL)` (available in `#include <unistd.h>`))

Comment: Thanks. I changed the name to colourful_small.jpg but didn't help. Then I downloaded a PNG file to find out whether progressive JPEG is the problem. It gave me the same error. I'm not sure how am I supposed to do the last part of your solution though. I included the library you told me to and I did cout << getcwd(NULL); It said it doesn't know what getcwd means. Could you please further explain to me how am I supposed to do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'm somewhat surprised that the "correct answer" has a comment saying that it's not working... anyway:

Your rendering (drawing) need to take place in every iteration of your loop:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    sf::RenderWindow(window);
    window.create(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "My window");

    sf::Texture img;
    if(!img.loadFromFile("colorfull small.jpg")) return 0;

    sf::Sprite sprite;
    sprite.setTexture(img);

     while(window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while(window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if(event.type == sf::Event::Closed) window.close();
        }

        // drawing needs to take place every loop right HERE 
        window.clear();
        window.draw(sprite);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why would I need to draw it over every time an event is called? I just wanted to draw it once and let it be displayed, without changing anything about it.

Comment: That's not how computers work. If you draw it once, your window will not redraw, it will look as if your program crashed. Running a program means drawing graphics all the time. If you have business programs, they may be content with redrawing when special events happen, like size change or other windows covering your window and being removed, but in general... you redraw frequently. Just look at the tutorials. They even say you need not be afraid to redraw 1000 items each frame... that's way below what todays graphic cards can deliver.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting [the official tutorial](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.1/start-osx.php):

> the project comes with a basic example in main.cpp and a helper function: std::string resourcePath(void); in ResourcePath.hpp and ResourcePath.mm. The usefulness of this function, as illustrated in the provided example, is to get in a convenient way access to the Resources folder of your application bundle.

This means you have to write something like:

```
#include "ResourcePath.hpp"
:
:
if (!icon.loadFromFile(resourcePath() + "colorfull small.jpg")) {
:
:
```

(Inspired by the default code generated by the project template.)

nvoigt's answer is also very important.